# Passing a class attribute as a function argument?

Tags: python

Can I pass the variable name I am looking for as an argument? In the def below, the stat argument is meant to update the **.stat** in the function. (see arrow) I keep getting an error:

```
 print("game result :" +(self._playerHxDic[name][str(i)].stat))
```

> AttributeError: 'GameHx' object has no attribute 'stat'

```
def getStats(self,name,num_of_games,stat):
    games = self._playerHxDic[name].keys()
    gameNums = []
    for i in games:
        gameNums.append(int(i))
    gameNums.sort()
    if len(gameNums) > num_of_games:
        gamelist = [int(x) for x in gameNums[-num_of_games:]]
        points = 0
        for i in gamelist:
            points += statDicint(self._playerHxDic[name][i].stat)#<-- 
        return points/num_of_games
    else: return None
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Update the stat variable of the GameHx? Get the stat variable from the GameHx object? Please clarify your question.

Comment: solved! i needed       .__getattribute__(stat)) method

Answer (score 0):

```
getattr(self._playerHxDic[name][i], stat)
```

[Documentation of getattr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)